# eval gets executed even thought ng-csp directive is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, content-security-policy

I have enabled ngCsp using the ng-csp directive:

```
<body ng-app="PM" ng-csp ng-cloak>
```

Why I am still able to execute the following `eval` in my code without any angular errors?

```
$scope.searchform = {
    searchExpression : "alert('hi')"
}

$scope.handleChange = function () {
    eval($scope.searchform.searchExpression);
}

<input type="text" ng-model="searchform.searchExpression" ng-change="handleChange(searchform.searchExpression)">
```

Am I not understanding what ng-csp is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AngularJS uses `Function(string)` generated functions as a speed optimization. Applying the ngCsp directive will cause Angular to use CSP compatibility mode. When this mode is on AngularJS will evaluate all expressions up to 30% slower than in non-CSP mode, but no security violations will be raised.

[From the Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)

What this means is that using `ng-csp` will change how *Angular* behaves, as it will manually process things rather than take `eval`-based shortcuts. This is useful if you are using CSP on your document.

It is not some magical way of changing how JavaScript works.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it perhaps would console error "Don't use eval" or something like that